# In the film "Signs", was the book they read (about a flying saucer burning a house) based on real events?

Tags: signs

(Within the universe of the movie, not actual real life) I'm just curious. In the movie Graham, Bo and Morgan read a book about aliens, and find a page with a saucer burning a house with laser beams. Did this happen within the universe of the movie. I can imagine it happened in real life (within the movie universe).

Answer (score 1):

The book is, according to the [script](https://www.scriptslug.com/assets/uploads/scripts/signs-2002.pdf), the kind of [pseudo-scientific nonsense](https://www.library.miami.edu/gleason/ufos/index.html) that you find in every book store. The pictures themselves are merely illustrative of the two reasons that the author (the distinguished Dr. Bimboo) thinks aliens might come to visit Earth.

> MORGAN (CONT’D): To make contact in the spirit of exploration and furthering the
> knowledge of the universe.
>
> [Graham looks at an illustration of a small, bulbous headed
> figure shaking hands with a bearded human.]
>
> MORGAN (CONT’D): Or the other reason... They're hostile. They've used up the
> resources on their planet and are looking to harvest our planet next.
>
> [Morgan turns the page. There is a picture of a house. A space ship is hovering over the home shooting laser beams at it. Beat.]

There's no good indication that aliens are real in the Signs universe

> until they turn up and try to murder us all, obviously.

Comment: Does it really say "pseudo-scientific" nonsense?

Comment: @RobJackson - They're literally wearing tinfoil hats as they read it.

Comment: Yes but you're just assuming that's what the director thought.

Comment: Although I can vouch that M Night Shamylan to quote what someone in the "Analysis of 'Signs'" video says, did play a lot of that off for comedy rather than make it too serious. Still I think it's a jumping to conclusions. I read the original script, he didn't insult the book.

Comment: @RobJackson - It doesn't appear to be a sensible study on the subject. It has pictures to illustrate and no author note on the back cover. The dad insults the book author, referring to "Dr. Bimboo" in a funny voice.

Comment: I mean I guess... and read my previous statement, he did seem to play off the scenes with the family falling into obsession for comedy, so you might be right to some decree.

Comment: Now on retrospect you're right it did seem like some charlatan wrote that book. Still however, it's eerie that the book did to some decree say some of what DID end up happening, don't cha think?

Comment: No author note? Yeah you're right the writer was a charlatan and I think Graham knew it too

Comment: @RobJackson - Educated guesswork or is it all [actually real and the government covered it all up](https://media.giphy.com/media/3oEjI789af0AVurF60/giphy.gif)?

Comment: No I agree with you, when I think about it. No note about the author, it seems Graham knew the writer was a charlatan. So I give you that. On a side note, however, it deem seem that some of the things in the book came true. Isn't that kinda eerie? It's as if the writer had some premonitions...

Comment: As if at best Dr. Bimboo had a lot of spare time, or at worst, he was a professional fraudster. Hahaha that's a good one I'm glad you reminded me. When I was a kid I was more on Morgan's side. As a young adult I understand Graham more. Or at the very leat I'm more balanced. Not that Morgan was wrong on what happened, but on the book yes.

Comment: Why'd they suspend you from chatting?

Comment: @RobJackson - Because I'm too awesome for chat

Comment: Is there anything I can do to get you unbanned?

Comment: @RobJackson - Unlikely.

Comment: @Valorum Best use of spoiler tags I've seen in quite a while.